# What is coresponding relation about colors and texture coordinates in 3D software?

Tags: opengl, 3d, maya

In many 3D softwares there is a panel to display texture coordinates in geometry, like this

[image]

How to map the different color on geometry to texture coordinates?

Where can I find information about it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texture coordiates go from (0,0) to (1, 1). They're  2D vectors and colors are often represented by a 3D vector (red, green, blue). What you get is your UV coordinate as a color (r : UV.x, g: UV.y , 0).

Comment: Thank you for saving my time!

Answer (score 1):

In maya there is such one click solution as much as I know. But you can use the samplerInfo node and connect its uv-output to any color node, e.g. a blendColors node. Set the blender to 1 and connect the uvs to the first input. This works.